# How do you create an executable file when debugging Swift in VSCode using CodeLLDB?

Tags: swift, visual-studio-code, path, lldb, codelldb

I'm trying to run/debug Swift code in VSCode, and I'm running into a problem. Whenever I try to run the Swift file, I get a message that says "unable to find executable for '<full program path from C: drive to file, no extension>.exe'. The problem is, I don't know why it's looking for a .exe when I want to run a Swift file. Does someone know what's going on?

```
{
    "launch": {
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Launch",
                "type": "lldb",
                "request": "launch",
                "program": "/C:/desir_7411ic3/Desktop/Programs/swift/swifttest",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

### I tried a few different forms of the path

just the folder and the program
file with extension
combinations of the two above

Comment: lldb doesn't attempt to decode `#!` constructs in interpreted source files to figure out what it should actually launch in order to run the script.  lldb only works on compiled binaries.  So you will have to make a VSCode project that builds your source files into a binary.

Comment: I didn't put this in the answer because it sounds like you also want to know how to build such a binary with VSCode but I'm not familiar with VSCode.  But you will have to do that.